# Django query, count base on N minute

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class Indicator(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)


class IndicatorValue(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)       
    indicator = models.ForeignKey(Indicator)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to get an array containing the number of IndicatorValue of an indicator X for each N minutes slot:

```
[
    {Datetime(t): Count(IndicatorValue == X, t<=time<t+N)}
    {Datetime(t+N minute): Count(IndicatorValue == X, t+N<=time<t+2N)}
]
```

I tried this:

```
IndicatorValue.objects.filter(indicator_id=X).extra({'hour': "date_part(\'hour\', \"time\")", 'minute': "date_part(\'minute\', \"time\")"}).values('hour', 'minute').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

But I have several issues:

1. I have the count of the interval if I have a row. When I dont have a row, I don't have: `{Datetime(t'): O }`.
2. It's a per minute count. I have to sum on the N minutes to get the distribution.
3. It's not a `Datetime` but a (hour, minute) couple.

Is-there a simple solution for this problem with Django?

**EDIT1:**

I found `date_trunc` to keep the `Datetime` format:

```
IndicatorValue.objects.filter(indicator_id=6).extra({'minute_interval': "date_trunc(\'minute\', \"time\")"}).values('minute_interval').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

Point 1 & 2 are still unsolved.

**EDIT2:**

I found a way to get the N minutes interval:

```
IndicatorValue.objects.filter(indicator_id=6).extra({'minute_interval': "SELECT date_trunc(\'hour\', \"time\") + INTERVAL \'5 min\' * ROUND(date_part(\'minute\', \"time\") / 5.0) "}).values('minute_interval').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

This generate the following query:

```
SELECT (SELECT date_trunc('hour', "time") + INTERVAL '5 min' * ROUND(date_part('minute', "time") / 5.0) ) AS "minute_interval", COUNT("app_monitoring_indicatorvalue"."id") AS "count" FROM "app_monitoring_indicatorvalue" WHERE "app_monitoring_indicatorvalue"."indicator_id" = 6  GROUP BY (SELECT date_trunc('hour', "time") + INTERVAL '5 min' * ROUND(date_part('minute', "time") / 5.0) )
```

Solution tested with `PostgreSQL`: [Source](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Round_time).

Point 1 is still remaining.

**EDIT3:**

I have one solution based on `execute`:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''\
select g, count(a.id) \
from generate_series( \
    %(from)s::timestamp, \
    %(to)s::timestamp, \
    %(slice)s::interval \
) as g \
   left outer join app_monitoring_indicatorvalue as a on \
      a.time >= g and a.time < g + %(slice)s::interval \
group by g \
order by g \
''', {'slice': '5 minutes', 'from': '20150121 9:00', 'to': '20150121 13:00'})
cursor.fetchall()
```

This solved all the points. I can't use `raw` as I can't return the `primary key` of `IntervalValue`.
Is-this the best way with django?